# How to get the sum of transactions per month in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, charts

I'm building a transaction application and need to display the data in charts using chart.js. I don't know how to get the sum for each month of the year.

my model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    trans_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)  
    trans_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    group_id = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    trans_amount = models.FloatField()
    trans_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="contribution")  

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.trans_id)
```

How can I get the sum totals?

Comment: from django.db.models import Sum, Q 

Transaction.objects.filter(trans_date__year="2022").annotate(jan_transactions=Sum('trans_amount', filter=Q(trans_date__month=1)))

Comment: @SardarFaisal why dont post an answer instead? ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) database function

Give this a try

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

Transaction.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth("trans_date"))
    .values("month")
    .annotate(sum=Sum("trans_amount"))
```

The reslut will look like

```
[
    {
        "month": "2022-04-01T00:00:00Z",
        "sum": 10.0
    },
    {
        "month": "2022-05-01T00:00:00Z",
        "sum": 20.0
    }
]
```

Comment: Can I also track them by year and month?

Comment: yes, there is a [TruncYear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncYear) function

Comment: How can I archive that? I'm new to django

Comment: Just change that TruncMonth with TruncYear ```Transaction.objects.annotate(month=TruncYear("trans_date")).values("year").annotate(sum=Sum("trans_amount"))```